# What's the difference between arc4random and random?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What's the difference between arc4random and random?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`random` is known to be predictable and thus not to be used for secure pseudo-random number generation.  `arc4random` is a newer, less predictable pseudo-random number generator.  If you are not using it for anything secure, `random` will work fine.

Comment: `random` is also significantly faster than `arc4random`, which is why you'd ever use it at all.

Comment: @Colin Cislason: How much faster? Does it make any difference if you aren't creating 1000nds of random numbers?

Comment: @Emil It may not have that much effect. I haven't run any tests myself. See the following link for a test, but this compares with `rand` and uses many iterations: http://www.indieappsalliance.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, random() may or may not be the old, reliable, and predictable UNIX random().  On modern FreeBSD systems, and Linux 2.6 systems that have the /dev/random device, the default random() implementation reads from /dev/random until it is exhausted.  This is likely to produce somewhat better random numbers than any numerical sequence generator, depending on the sources of randomness you've stirred into /dev/random.

Consulting the documentation (man pages, etc) for the system you are deploying the program on is highly suggested.

Comment: Really?  -1?  You really *should* go read the effing man pages before hitting that down arrow.

Comment: I can't speak for the user voting you down, but the question is tagged 'iphone'.  An answer starting with "Depending on your system" and mentioning Linux might not be an appropriate answer.