# Shuffle NSMutableArray objective-c

Tags: objective-c, random, nsmutablearray, shuffle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)
>   [Non repeating random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617630/non-repeating-random-numbers)

How to get random indexes of NSMutableArray without repeating?
I have NSMutableArray *audioList. I want to play each track in shuffle mode, without repeating. How to do this in the best way?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray

Comment: @Timur: yes it is.  This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656 is aexactly what you want.

Comment: I don't want to reorder my array. I want to get indexes and reorder them in another array.

Comment: @Timur:  Well copy the array then and shuffle the copy (use `-mutableCopy`).

Answer (score 4):

See the code below:

```
int length = 10; // int length = [yourArray count];
NSMutableArray *indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) [indexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
NSMutableArray *shuffle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];
while ([indexes count])
{
    int index = rand()%[indexes count];
    [shuffle addObject:[indexes objectAtIndex:index]];
    [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
[indexes release];
for (int i=0; i<[shuffle count]; i++)
    NSLog(@"%@", [shuffle objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Now in shuffle you will have indexes of your array without repeating.

Hope, this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Nekto's answer is great, but I would change two things:

1) Instead of using rand(), use arc4random() for less predictable results (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794201/whats-the-difference-between-arc4random-and-random)):

```
int index = arc4random() % [indexes count];
```

2) To output contents of "shuffle", use [myArray description] (no need to use a for loop):

```
NSLog(@"shuffle array: %@", [shuffle description]);
```

Comment: To simplify further, calling `NSLog(@"shuffle array: %@", shuffle);` is equivalent to `NSLog(@"shuffle array: %@", [shuffle description]);` since `%@` sends the message `description` to the object.